# Finding slope between coordinates stored in List(Of Point) data types

Tags: vb.net, list, point

I am working in VB 2008. I have used a List(Of Point) data type to store coordinates of certain pixel values from a bitmap:

```
'This code is in a loop
Dim bpCoordinates As New List(Of Point)
If pixelClr > 72 Then
bpCoordinates.Add(New Point(FrameNumber, y))
End If
```

I want to calculate the slope between the stored points in the list using (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1).
The problem I have is accessing the points in my list. I don't how to do this.

I looked online and can't find any way of extracting the individual coordinate points from the list. Any suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they're listed in a List, you can access element directly like you would in an array - although this is inefficient.

```
'Returns the nth list element
Dim p As Point = bpCoordinates(n)
```

Storing it in an array would be much better, especially if your list is long.

```
Dim pointArray As Point() = bpCoordinates.ToArray
```

Just iterate through your list or array normally afterwards.

```
Dim slope As Double

For index As Integer = 0 To pointArray.Length - 1
     slope = (pointArray(index + 1).Y - pointArray(index).Y) / (pointArray(index + 1).X - pointArray(index).X)
     'Do fun stuff with slope
Next
```